# Is there any module for booking?

Tags: 7, bookings

A  module for `Booking` type system which allow me to add Different Hotels, Apartments etc. in Different countries. I want to show Availability calender also.

I tried [uc_hotel](https://drupal.org/project/uc_hotel) and [AG Reservation](https://drupal.org/project/agreservations) but both don't meet my requirements.

1. I need price calculation based on room selected. If a user select only two rooms of an apartment and the apartment has 4 rooms, then the price is based on the selected room; filters are based on availability.
2. I need search functionality based on location, bedroom, people capacity, accommodation type, offers; the price is based on the extra facility provided.

Comment: Comparisons are usually not constructive, unless there is only one module that tries to solve given problem and is supported and maintained. And very specific requirements always call for custom modules anyway.

Comment: @Mołot I am looking for module that nearly meets my condition so my customization can be little.

Comment: Then I think you need to rephrase your title to reflect what you want, and remove comparison-provoking "best module" part, just make it "module that would allow me to ..." or something like this. Or, if you insist on *best*, "best module to implement ... on".

Answer (score 4):

Then Drupal [Rooms](https://drupal.org/project/rooms) is the only option for you and it match your requirement for room calculation, it will update the pricing  depend upon the rooms selected . Rooms is a booking and room management solution for hotels, vacation rentals and B&Bs.

> It allows an accommodation owner to:
>
> - Create rooms and assign availability (or on hold states) via a calendar.
> - Manage pricing for rooms using calendars that allow to set pricing for entire seasons or just change it for specific dates.
> - Define optional add-ons for rooms.
> - Charge either per-night or per-person.
> - Handle children discounts.
> - Create bookings and keep customer records.
> - Make rooms available for booking with a availability search functionality and/or calendar - handling both immediate bookings and bookings following owner confirmation.
> - Search by Room Type.
> - Full integration with Commerce to manage payments, a range of different payment gateways, and a host of other e-commerce features.
> - Accept full or partial payments (deposits) using Commerce features.